# Telegraf js formatting

Tags: node.js, telegraf

How do I create a block of code using markdown in telegraf.js

```
ctx.reply("\`\`\`code\`\`\`", {parse_mode: "Markdown") don't work
```

````
ctx.reply("```code```", {parse_mode: "Markdown") also dont work, help me please
````